# How to trigger an event only after id is assigned to backbone model after save() method

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-model

I am using backbone model in my application but the problem is that I want to perform some function after id is assigned to newly created Model. I am using this

```
activeWidget.on('sync', this.addToCollectionWidget(activeWidget));
```

But this.addToCollectionWidget method is called before id is assigned to the model. Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to trigger an event when a Backbone model is saved?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883653/how-to-trigger-an-event-when-a-backbone-model-is-saved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the function in a callback. Your current code will work if `addToCollectionWidget` return a function.

This should work:

```
activeWidget.on('sync', function() {
    this.addToCollectionWidget(activeWidget); //you should careful with `this` in the callback context.
});
```

Comment: Thanks brother. One more question this.addToCollectionWidget is being called on both save() and destroy() how can I stop it from execution when  destroy() is performed. Thanks a lot.